# UI button not working

Tags: unity

Every time I try to click on the button, nothing happens. I am linking some picks to help everyone answer my question.

I have added a event system. I have a canvas. The button is set to interactable.

[image: The restart button script]
[image: My heirachy]
[image: Inspector]

Comment: This could be a weird Unity thing, but try removing the "static" method modifier then use the dropdown menu to select the method (instead of MonoScript.name)

Comment: @MDragon00 I even tried that. Originally it wasn't static, I then tried it out with the static keyword.

Comment: Moreover in the dropdown menu I am just getting a option for no function and Monoscript main function.

Comment: You should change back to non static. It won't work any way. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/840906/ugui-ui-button-onclick-static-methods.html

Comment: Regarding non static, trying to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:
[image]
it looks like you directly dropped the script instead of the object to which it is attached.

Let's say your "Restart" script is attached to MainCamera. You need to assign Main Camera in the field marked red.Then select a script attached to main Camera, which is Restart, from that select a method which is ReStartGame().

When you do that, the field marked green would say: Restart.RestartGame

Answer (score 0):

Put the Debug.Log before the Loadlevel instruction. What happens now is, LoadLevel is executed and everything is destroyed, including the button which was clicked.
When new scene is loaded, everything in current scene is automatically destroyed. If you want an object to be present across multiple scenes, check the manual for DontDestroyOnLoad().

Comment: The debug log is just for checking whether the button is being clicked on and still not functions as a restart button.

Comment: @AkshatMalik if you comment out the Application.LoadLevel line and then click the button, does the debug statement still run? (Just a quick test, may help out). And as a side note, you shouldn't need that event system just for a button to activate a public method.

Comment: @AkshatMalik whether you treat it as restart feature or not, it actually is loading new level. Just put Debug.Log before the loadlevel

Comment: @SanSolo well i did, and still nothing happened.

Comment: What is the name of the object to which Restart script is attached?